# Menu token not working

Tags: tokens, 7

I am Using menu token module to access pages related particular user, I am getting issue while selecting path in token menu using replacement patterns. can any one explains on what basis it will take the link and direct to the page. i tried to use [node:content-type:name], As there are so many content types created in my site, so how it will take the specific content type which is related with the node.

kindly suggest me if there are alternatives for this.. i am fed up by trying this whole day.

Comment: With all due respect, I don't think it is right to copy the exactly same answer to the duplicate question from other question.

Comment: I have added coz the answer should be available to all possible searches.... i can delete my answer.. you post it here i will accept it.. sorry my friend

Comment: No need to apologize :) Sharing the solutions is always good. But, we should always avoid to have duplicate contents.